# Shorten the refs when using: git log --graph --pretty=oneline --decorate=full --oneline

Tags: git

I'm using

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline --decorate=full --oneline
```

to get the following commit graph:

> * 221b95b (HEAD, refs/remotes/origin/master, refs/remotes/origin/HEAD, refs/remotes/upstream/master, refs/heads/master) Formatting commit

but showing the full refs path is inconvenient as it is too long.
is there a way to shorten it to get the paths shorten as follows?:

> * 221b95b (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, upstream/master, master) Formatting commit

Comment: `--oneline` means `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `--decorate` instead of `--decorate=full`, since `short` is the default value of `--decorate`, as stated in the [`git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) (bold emphasis mine):

> ```
> --decorate[=short|full|no]
> ```
>
> Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown. If `short` is specified, the ref name prefixes `refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/` and `refs/remotes/` will not be printed. If `full` is specified, the full ref name (including prefix) will be printed. **The default option is** `short`.

Also, as [jthill commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174482/shorten-the-refs-when-using-git-log-graph-pretty-oneline-decorate-full/24177026#comment37314712_24174482), `--pretty=oneline` is redundant, since `--oneline` already lists commits on one line each:

> `--oneline` means `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`.

So putting it all together:

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline
```

Comment: git log --graph --decorate --oneline works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `--decorate` (which defaults to `short`) instead of `--decorated=full`.

Also `--pretty=oneline` is redundant since you're already used `--oneline`, which is a shorthand for `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`.

Ultimately, just do

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline
```

Result:

```
* 73017eb (HEAD, origin/master, master) A commit message
```